# Artillery.io - Printing variables that you capture from JSON response

Tags: artillery

I can't get Artillery IO to pass. Is there a way to print the values of the variables I'm capturing? I couldn't find this in the docs.

I return an array:

```
          capture:
            json: "$[0]"
            as: "body"
```

how could I print `body` to debug why Artillery is failing?

Answer (score 2):

```
config:
  target: "http://localhost:8080"
  http:
    timeout: 20 
scenarios:
  - name:
    flow:
      - get:
          url: /api/docs/swagger.json
          capture:
            - json: "$"
              as: body
      - log: "{{body}}"
```